# Center of solvable and semi simple lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I know center of non zero finite dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra is non-trivial.

And center of finite dimensional semi simple lie algebras (over char F=0) is trivial.

1. Can center of finite dimensional solvable Lie algebra trivial?
2. Let L finite dimensional semi simple over F (not necessarily algebraic closed nor char F =0 ) can we still say center is trivial ?

Comment: For 1. Yes, take the Lie algebra of upper triangular matrices. Its centre is trivial but it is solvable

Comment: The answer to 2 might depend on what your definition of semisimple is. As long as you are in characteristic $0$, all the standard definitions are equivalent so you have no problem. What is your definition for a semisimple LA in positive characteristic?

Comment: But scalar matrices are in center. so this won't work @Callum

Comment: Fdml lie algebra L is semisimple if rad(L) =0. could you give reference for the equivalences specifically why center has to be trivial @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: If your definition of "semisimple" is that the radical is $0$, then just think for a moment to convince yourself that the centre of a Lie algebra is always contained in the LA's radical, and you can answer your question 2.

Comment: Bourbaki's Lie volumes, book 1, §6 Th. 1 and Prop. 2 show that for a finite-dim. LA $L$ over a field of zero characteristic, the following are equivalent: i) The only abelian ideal of $L$ is zero ii) $rad(L)=0$ iii) the Kiling form of $L$ is non-degenerate iv) $L$ is the direct sum of simple Lie algebras, where a simple LA is defined as one that is not abelian and whose only ideals are zero and the full Lie algebra.

Comment: @Learner Sorry, add "tracefree" as a condition and that solves that

Answer (score 4):

Summarising the comments, there is a short answer:

1. Yes. Already the non-abelian Lie algebra in dimension $2$ over an arbitrary field has zero center and is solvable.
2. Yes. By the very definition of semisimple in the general case, $Z(L)\subseteq {\rm rad}(L)=0$.